# Add object to JSON file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to add a single object to a very large JSON file. So far I have parsed the entire file using FS and JSON.Parse, appended the JSON object in memory and then re-written the file.

I know FS has a method appendFile() but I was wondering if there was a solution that would support a single new JSON object?

Comment: I think you have described the easiest way already. Transform it into a JavaScript object, add another object to that and then change it back to a JSON Object

Comment: Depending of what *very large* means exactly, it may not worth finding another solution.

Comment: `appendFile` treats a file as a write-only byte stream. It appends bytes to the end, not caring for what the file contains. It cannot rewrite any existing bytes. It's suitable for log files and for not a lot else. JSON on the other hand is not a byte stream, it's a serialized data structure that needs parsing before you can do any modifications to it. `appendFile` is entirely the wrong tool for this job, don't look there. Load the file, parse it, modify the data structure, serialize it, write it. That's the only way (short of not using JSON at all – CSV would be `appendFile`-compatible).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960470/how-can-i-add-values-to-a-json-object-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

To add object to a JSON you should try using the `push()` function:

```
this.jsonObject.push({name1:this.value1, name2:this.value2, ...});
```