# How can I add values to a json object dynamically

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json object to which i want to add values that user enters. I am learning angular and i need to do this in angular. I looked a lot but did not see any method to do this easily. I only want to know how to add a pair of data to the json object
This is my code in typescript file.

```
 people: any[]=[{
          "name": "jacob",
          "age": 22 },
          {
          "name": "sruthi",
          "age": 29 }
      
  ]
```

I want to insert values as the user enters different names and age.
This is my html code

```
  <input type="text" class="frm-control" placeholder="Enter Name" (change)="insert_name($event.target.value)"> &nbsp;
  <input type="text" class="frm-control" placeholder="Enter Age" (change)="insert_age($event.target.value)">
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px;" (onclick)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the push() method

```
this.people.push({name:this.name, age:this.age})
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `this.people.push({name:this.name, age:this.age})` Thanks a lot i was looking for an easy method just like this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be `people.push(<person>)`. To do it the Angular way, or just in general, I would recommend making a `Person` class instead of using `any` type.

```js
 class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
 }
 
 const people = [];
 people.push(new Person('Jacob', 22));
 people.push(new Person('Sruthi', 29));


console.log(people);
```

When someone selects your Button, it will essentially call a method that `push`es the new `Person` into your `people` array.

I would recommend setting up Reactive Forms to take advantage of all the form "stuff" that comes with (validation, submission, modeling, etc...)

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms